# Best way to remove item from mutableStateListOf in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a list of `mutableStateListOf`. I want to remove the item efficiently. I am asking this my data list is huge number of items. I tried some code but I am not sure this is correct way. If you have any suggestion to improve code, please provide an example.

**NameItem**

```
data class NameItem(val name: String, val number: Long)
```

**NameViewModel**

```
class NameViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

    val nameList = mutableStateListOf<NameItem>()

    private fun removeItem(name: String, removeIndex: Int) {
        val itemForRemoval = nameList.getOrNull(removeIndex)
        if (itemForRemoval?.name.equals(name, true)) {
            nameList.remove(itemForRemoval)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to check the name *and* the index? Removing is much more efficient if you only use the index: `list.removeAt(index)`.

If you do want to check both, the code you posted is mostly fine, except I'd still do the remove using the index, that saves a O(n) lookup.

Comment: yes I want to check the name and index both..